# create triggers - error at DECLARE

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, declare

i learn triggers from http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers
and i have:

```
create trigger bi_emps_fer before insert on emps for each row
begin

    declare newsal numeric default 0;
    declare namelength, l_loop int default 0;

    set namelength = length(new.emp_name);

    while l_loop < namelength do

       set newsal := newsal   new.salary;

       set l_loop := l_loop   1;

    end while;

    set new.salary = newsal;

end
```

and error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4

why?
i use MySQL 5.5.8 and phpmyadmin 3.3.9

Comment: Have you tried declaring namelength and l_loop on different lines?

Comment: yes, but error is this line: "declare newsal numeric default 0;"

Comment: Can `0` be a default for NUMERIC?  Do you have to say `0.0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you specify delimiters ?

```
delimiter #

create trigger bi_emps_fer before insert on emps for each row
begin

    declare newsal decimal(10,2) default 0;

    // do sql stuff here but not what you're doing !

    set new.salary = newsal;

end#

delimiter ;
```

Comment: @TrueBlue10 I understand. Sometimes, I also have these crocodiles chase me around, and they just won't stop until I can create phpmyadmin triggers properly.