# How to create a MySQL trigger in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I want to create a trigger in MySQL.  I run following commands:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_money BEFORE INSERT ON money
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> UPDATE accounts SET balance=10.0;
    -> END;
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)
```

But when I run above SQL in phpmyadmin I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near '' at line 4
```

what's wrong here?  How do I create a trigger?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused by not changing the delimiters temporarily as you did via CLI.  Try either:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_money BEFORE INSERT ON money
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE accounts SET balance=10.0;
```

or

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_money BEFORE INSERT ON money
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE accounts SET balance=10.0;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

See: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292158/create-triggers-error-at-declare) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003869/error-1064-in-trigger-creation-in-mysql).