# MySQL Trigger to Auto generating a number if not supplied

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Is it possible to auto generate a number if nothing is supplied for a column in the table

```
#SurveyId,Name,PhoneNumber
1,David,071234234
1,John, NULL
```

expected output

```
#SurveyId,Name,PhoneNumber
1,David,071234234
1,John, 3274985AUTO
```

I would like to write a trigger for my table to carry out the auto generation option; i would like to use UUID() for auto generating number

syntax error:

```
15:10:23    CREATE TRIGGER mobilecheck BEFORE INSERT ON reg02_maininfo  `FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.farmermobile IS NULL THEN SET NEW.farmermobile = floor(rand()*900000)+100000   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2  0.0015 sec`
```

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? If you can upgrade to the latest patch in 8.0; you can set expressions as Default value for a column. Then you can use `UUID()` function

Comment: Typically auto increment columns are not columns into which you would want to directly insert data.  What is the logic behind the generated phone number?

Comment: mysql version 5.7.23 @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: Are you saying you want phone number to be the primary key?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i do not want a null value and would rather have an autogenerated number for my application purpose

Comment: @P.Salmon it is already part of a composite key

Comment: Just have an AI. Stop with all this phonenumber PK nonsense.

Comment: And your composite key contains which columns? And does your table have an id column other than survey id?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy  none of the answers provided solved my problem; i am looking for a trigger not a select statement

Comment: @MirieriMogaka how could anyone guess you needed a trigger if you didn't specify it?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy i edited my question apologies for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL trigger in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869629/how-to-create-a-mysql-trigger-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way

```
SELECT SurveyId, Name, IFNULL(PhoneNumber,floor(rand()*900000)+100000) as PhoneNumber FROM table
```

I did not add an `AUTO` at the end as if the field only accepts an integer it will give you an error.

You could also update your table to directly replace all null values

```
UPDATE Table SET PhoneNumber = floor(rand()*900000)+100000
WHERE PhoneNumber IS NULL;
```

For a trigger you could use the following :

```
CREATE TRIGGER phonecheck BEFORE INSERT ON tablename FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.PhoneNumber IS NULL THEN SET NEW.PhoneNumber = floor(rand()*900000)+100000; END IF;
```

Comment: i am looking for a trigger that can be executed when data is inserted into my table, I have tried using the following but it seems not to be exactly what i am looking for

Comment: @MirieriMogaka if you don't specify it I can't help ^^

Answer (score -1):

COALESCE to fetch it if it's non-null, FLOOR+RAND to get a random number otherwise, CONCAT to add `AUTO` at the end?

```
SELECT `#SurveyId`,`Name`,COALESCE(`PhoneNumber`,CONCAT((FLOOR(RAND()*(9999999-1000000+1))+1000000),'AUTO')) AS PhoneNumber
```